# Arbitrary precision number formatting / money_format?

Tags: php, string-formatting, currency, number-formatting, arbitrary-precision

Is there an arbitrary-precision alternative to [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) available that could take a string instead of a float as a parameter?

It's not that I plan on doing calculations on trillions of monetary units, but after going through the trouble to properly handle monetary arithmetic without abusing floats, it'd be nice to have a function that doesn't spew random numbers after about 15 digits, even if users decide to give it nonsense data. Or, hey, maybe someone wants to buy *two* sticks of gum in [Zimbabwe dollars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aZimbabwe_%24100_trillion_2009_Obverse.jpg)?

I hesitate to use regular expressions because I was hoping to make use of the localization of money_format.

edit - found a workable solution; see below

Comment: round() or number_format() are not good enough ? just just need to cast the string to float.

Comment: @Cesar - Casting it explicitly doesn't do anything for the rounding errors. Try casting a large string number (~20 digits or so) to float and you'll get something like 3.17817313888E+20. Feed it into a formatting function that takes a float like money_format or number_format and you'll get random, incorrect garbage after so many digits. That just comes with using floats -- you've got about fifteen digits of precision, I believe. I'm aware of how anal-retentive this is, but still -- it seems a function like that should take a string parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cobbled together from the commenter-submitted functions on PHP's site [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php#95293) and [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php#89060). Edited to work with arbitrary-precision parameters.

```
class format {
    function money($format, $number) 
    { 
        // Takes plain-format, arbitrary-length decimal string (eg: '123456789123456789.123456')
        // Returns localized monetary string, truncated at the hundredth value after the decimal point.
        // (eg: $ 123,456,789,123,456,789.12)
        $regex  = '/%((?:[\^!\-]|\+|\(|\=.)*)([0-9]+)?'. 
                  '(?:#([0-9]+))?(?:\.([0-9]+))?([in%])/'; 
        if (setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 0) == 'C') { 
            setlocale(LC_MONETARY, ''); 
        } 
        $locale = localeconv(); 
        preg_match_all($regex, $format, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER); 
        foreach ($matches as $fmatch) { 
            $value = (string) $number;
            $flags = array( 
                'fillchar'  => preg_match('/\=(.)/', $fmatch[1], $match) ? 
                               $match[1] : ' ', 
                'nogroup'   => preg_match('/\^/', $fmatch[1]) > 0, 
                'usesignal' => preg_match('/\+|\(/', $fmatch[1], $match) ? 
                               $match[0] : '+', 
                'nosimbol'  => preg_match('/\!/', $fmatch[1]) > 0, 
                'isleft'    => preg_match('/\-/', $fmatch[1]) > 0 
            ); 
            $width      = trim($fmatch[2]) ? (int)$fmatch[2] : 0; 
            $left       = trim($fmatch[3]) ? (int)$fmatch[3] : 0; 
            $right      = trim($fmatch[4]) ? (int)$fmatch[4] : $locale['int_frac_digits']; 
            $conversion = $fmatch[5]; 

            $positive = true; 
            if ($value[0] == '-') { 
                $positive = false; 
                $value  = bcmul($value, '-1');
            } 
            $letter = $positive ? 'p' : 'n'; 

            $prefix = $suffix = $cprefix = $csuffix = $signal = ''; 

            $signal = $positive ? $locale['positive_sign'] : $locale['negative_sign']; 
            
            if ($locale["{$letter}_sign_posn"] == 1 && $flags['usesignal'] == '+')
                $prefix = $signal; 
            elseif ($locale["{$letter}_sign_posn"] == 2 && $flags['usesignal'] == '+') 
                $suffix = $signal; 
            elseif ($locale["{$letter}_sign_posn"] == 3 && $flags['usesignal'] == '+')
                $cprefix = $signal; 
            elseif ($locale["{$letter}_sign_posn"] == 4 && $flags['usesignal'] == '+')
                $csuffix = $signal; 
            elseif ($flags['usesignal'] == '(' || $locale["{$letter}_sign_posn"] == 0) {
                $prefix = '('; 
                $suffix = ')'; 

            } 
            if (!$flags['nosimbol']) { 
                $currency = $cprefix . 
                            ($conversion == 'i' ? $locale['int_curr_symbol'] : $locale['currency_symbol']) . 
                            $csuffix; 
            } else { 
                $currency = ''; 
            } 
            $space  = $locale["{$letter}_sep_by_space"] ? ' ' : ''; 

            $value = format::number($value, $right, $locale['mon_decimal_point'], 
                     $flags['nogroup'] ? '' : $locale['mon_thousands_sep']);
                     
            $value = @explode($locale['mon_decimal_point'], $value); 

            $n = strlen($prefix) + strlen($currency) + strlen($value[0]); 
            if ($left > 0 && $left > $n) { 
                $value[0] = str_repeat($flags['fillchar'], $left - $n) . $value[0]; 
            } 
            $value = implode($locale['mon_decimal_point'], $value); 
            if ($locale["{$letter}_cs_precedes"]) { 
                $value = $prefix . $currency . $space . $value . $suffix; 
            } else { 
                $value = $prefix . $value . $space . $currency . $suffix; 
            } 
            if ($width > 0) { 
                $value = str_pad($value, $width, $flags['fillchar'], $flags['isleft'] ? 
                         STR_PAD_RIGHT : STR_PAD_LEFT); 
            } 

            $format = str_replace($fmatch[0], $value, $format); 
        } 
        return $format; 
    } 
    
    function number  ($number  , $decimals = 2 , $dec_point = '.' , $sep = ',', $group=3   ){
        // Arbitrary-precision number formatting:
        // Takes plain-format, arbitrary-length decimal string (eg: '123456789123456789.123456').
        // Takes the same parameters as PHP's native number_format plus a flexible 'grouping' parameter. 
        // WARNINGS: Truncates -- does not round; not inherently locale-aware
        
        $num = (string) $number;   
        if (strpos($num, '.')) $num = substr($num, 0, (strpos($num, '.') + 1 + $decimals)); // truncate
        $num = explode('.',$num);
        while (strlen($num[0]) % $group) $num[0]= ' '.$num[0];
        $num[0] = str_split($num[0],$group);
        $num[0] = join($sep[0],$num[0]);
        $num[0] = trim($num[0]);
        $num = join($dec_point[0],$num);
        
        return $num;
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
 setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_ZW'); // pick your favorite hyperinflated currency
 $string = '123456789123456789.123456';
  
 echo "original string: " . 
  $string . "<br>";
  // 123456789123456789.123456
 echo "float cast - " . 
  ((float) $string) . "<br>";
  // 1.23456789123E+17
 echo "number_format original: " . 
  number_format($string, 4) . "<br>";
  // 123,456,789,123,456,768.0000
 echo "number_format new: " . 
  format::number($string, 4) . "<br>";
  // 123,456,789,123,456,789.1234
 echo "money_format original: " . 
  money_format('%n', $string) . "<br>";
  // Z$ 123,456,789,123,456,784.00 
 echo "money_format new: " . 
  format::money('%n',$string) . "<br>";
  // Z$ 123,456,789,123,456,789.12
```

Answer (score 0):

try the [NumberFormatter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php) class

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have that PECL extension to test it out, but it looks like that still a float as a paramter? Maybe I'm misunderstanding? The examples have a ton of digits, but most are insignificant and just rounded off.